# Python-Multithreading Time Sensitive Task

Tags: queue, python-2.7, python-multithreading

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep
#import thread
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
'''The idea is that there is a Seeker method that would search a location
for task, I have no idea how many task there will be, could be 1 could be 100.
Each task needs to be put into a thread, does its thing and finishes. I have
stripped down a lot of what this is really suppose to do just to focus on the
correct queuing and threading aspect of the program. The locking was just
me experimenting with locking'''
class Runner(Thread):
    current_queue_size = 0
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        data = queue.get()
        self.ID = data[0]
        self.timer = data[1]
        #self.lock = data[2]
        Runner.current_queue_size += 1
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        #self.lock.acquire()
        print "running {ID}, will run for: {t} seconds.".format(ID = self.ID,
                                                                t = self.timer)
        print "Queue size: {s}".format(s = Runner.current_queue_size)
        sleep(self.timer)        
        Runner.current_queue_size -= 1
        print "{ID} done, terminating, ran for {t}".format(ID = self.ID,
                                                                t = self.timer)
        print "Queue size: {s}".format(s = Runner.current_queue_size)
        #self.lock.release()
        sleep(1)
        self.queue.task_done()

def seeker():
    '''Gathers data that would need to enter its own thread.
    For now it just uses a count and random numbers to assign
    both a task ID and a time for each task'''
    queue = Queue()
    queue_item = {}
    count = 1
    #lock = thread.allocate_lock()
    while (count <= 40):
        random_number = randrange(1,350)
        queue_item[count] = random_number
        print "{count} dict ID {key}: value {val}".format(count = count, key = random_number,
                                                          val = random_number)
        count += 1

    for n in queue_item:
        #queue.put((n,queue_item[n],lock))
        queue.put((n,queue_item[n])) 
        '''I assume it is OK to put a tulip in and pull it out later'''
        worker = Runner(queue)
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()
    worker.join() 
    '''Which one of these is necessary and why? The queue object
    joining or the thread object'''

    #queue.join()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seeker()
```

I have put most of my questions in the code itself, but to go over the main points (Python2.7):

- I want to make sure I am not creating some massive memory leak for myself later.
- I have noticed that when I run it at a count of 40 in putty or VNC on
  my linuxbox that I don't always get all of the output, but when
  I use IDLE and Aptana on windows, I do.
- Yes I understand that the point of Queue is to stagger out your
  Threads so you are not flooding your system's memory, but the task at
  hand are time sensitive so they need to be processed as soon as they
  are detected regardless of how many or how little there are; I have
  found that when I have Queue I can clearly dictate when a task has
  finished as oppose to letting the garbage collector guess.
- I still don't know why I am able to get away with using either the
  .join() on the thread or queue object.
- Tips, tricks, general help.
- Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need a thread to monitor something to see if there are tasks that need to be done. If a task is found you want that to run in parallel with the seeker and other currently running tasks.

If this is the case  then I think you might be going about this wrong. Take a look at how the GIL works in Python. I think what you might really want here is multiprocessing.

Take a look at this from the pydocs:

CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.